# Shell action with awscli commands for s3 buckets in Oozie

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a shell script that does multiple s3 file list and move operations along with few basic shell commands. The script runs fine from command line, but gets killed when executed using *`oozie` shell action*!

I tried the simple `aws s3 ls` command as *`oozie` shell action*, which gets killed too.

So, wondering if it is possible to do such s3 operations in shell action or not.

Here is what's in the logs:

> `============================================================‌​===== >>> Invoking Shell command line now >> Exit code of the Shell command 1 <<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<< <<< Invocation of Main class completed <<< Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1] Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully –`

Note: awscli is installed in all the nodes and yarn user has access permission for the buckets. The script works fine in all the nodes from command line.

Comment: this is all I could find in job logs,

Comment: =================================================================

>>> Invoking Shell command line now >>

Exit code of the Shell command 1
<<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<<


<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully